# ProgrammingError("%s can not be used with MySQL" % s)

Tags: python, mysql-python

I want to insert the dataframe into table1 using the code below:

```
def insert(df):
    host='###'
    name='###'
    password='###'
    database='###'
    conn = pymysql.connect(host, user=name,passwd=password, db=database, connect_timeout=5,cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 ) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    cur.execute( sql, (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    return

for row in dataframe.itertuples():
    insert(row)
```

The error is showing below:

```
    cur.execute( sql, (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 161, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 140, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 115, in _escape_args
    return tuple(conn.literal(arg) for arg in args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 115, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(conn.literal(arg) for arg in args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 469, in literal
    return self.escape(obj, self.encoders)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 462, in escape
    return converters.escape_item(obj, self.charset, mapping=mapping)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py", line 26, in escape_item
    val = encoder(val, mapping)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py", line 58, in escape_float
    raise ProgrammingError("%s can not be used with MySQL" % s)
NameError: name 'ProgrammingError' is not defined
```

Anyone know what was wrong and how to solve the error?

Comment: Assuming your `insert` is like listed here, how should it know what `row` is? I suppose `row[0]` - `row[4]` are `None`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to check for all of the values like inf or NaN. You can place something like this on the end of the df processing to avoid such problems:

```
report = report.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
report = report.fillna(0)
```

Of course if you don't mind, that these values will be represented as zeros, which may be wrong in many situations. Then you have to find some other representation.

Answer (score 0):

ProgrammingError is not a built in error. It needs to be defined before you can use it. If its supposed to be defined by pymysql you need to import it with `from pymysql import ProgrammingError`.

Comment: I tried what you said--- import ProgrammingError, but shows same error.

Comment: You cant just do `import ProgrammingError`, you have to do `from pymysql import ProgrammingError`

Comment: I tried ----from pymysql import ProgrammingError, it seems like not working.

Comment: I tried it on my conputer and it works, what error are you getting?

Comment: it is the same error that I put it on the description

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem by checking that the data did not have NaN.